# Запись Object-а в Cookies JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Записываю в cookies при помощи jquery. Записываю объект `user`, у которого есть свойства.

Записываю так: `$.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(user), { expires: 7, path: '/' });`

в кукисах вижу такое: `%7B%22login%22%3A%22ADMIN%22%2C%22user_id%22%3A1%2C%22role%22%3A%22user%22%7D`.

Пробовал записывать без jquery записывает нормально. Но мне бы хотелось использовать jquery cookie. Подскажите как поправить это дело?

Comment: Я не понял что вам не нравится?

Comment: В чём проблема? Плагин кодирует всё "опасные" символы в `Percent-encoding` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ), ради безопасности.

Comment: @AlexeyTen то что оно так выглядит.

Comment: @Other тобишь это нормально?

Comment: @Other Проблема в том что мне нужно получить эти данный в Фильтре (JavaEE).

Comment: На сервере что ли?

Comment: @Tsyklop какая разница, декод сделаете и все будет хорошо у вас, так и должно быть

Comment: передавай объект напрямую, без _JSON.stringify_. Добавьте в вопрос ссылку на библиотеку, которой пользуетесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [флагом raw](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#raw)

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
```

Тогда при записи/чтении не будут использоваться функции `encodeURIComponent`/`decodeURIComponent`

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться [флагом json](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json),

```
$.cookie.json = true;
```

в данном случае вызов можно упростить до

```
$.cookie('user', user, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```